# Server side Omnifaces Push. PushContext is null

Tags: java, jsf, push, omnifaces

My question is about **server side** Omnifaces Push. So, I'm trying to integrate Omnifaces Push on a project, but I have a problem with PushContext instance when I try to send messages (PushContext instance is null).

### Techonology stack

- Tomcat 9.0.22
- Gradle 3.2.1
- JSF 2.2
- Primefaces 6.2
- Omnifaces 2.7.1
- cdi api 2.0
- weld servlet shaded 3.0.5.Final

I have a CDI container on I want to inject some PushContext instances (diferent push channels), but that instances aren't injected or are injected incorrectly as null. When I call to **notificar** method, *pushInicio* is null.

```
@Named
@Startup
public class ControladorMedidas
        implements Serializable {
    @Inject
    @Push(channel = "inicio")
    private PushContext pushInicio;

    @Inject
    @Push(channel = "centro")
    private PushContext pushCentro;

    ...
    private void notificar() {
        // pushInicio -> null
        pushInicio.send("some message");
    }
}
```

### Configuration

#### web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <resource-env-ref>
        <!-- Enable Weld CDI, also needs META-INF/context.xml entry -->
        <resource-env-ref-name>BeanManager</resource-env-ref-name>
        <resource-env-ref-type>javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager</resource-env-ref-type>
    </resource-env-ref>
    <!-- ... -->
    <!-- Configuracion PUSH OmniFaces -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.omnifaces.SOCKET_ENDPOINT_ENABLED</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <!-- ... -->
</web-app>
```

#### beans.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans
        xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd"
        bean-discovery-mode="annotated"
>
</beans>
```

#### context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context antiJARLocking="true" path="/servicios">
    <Resource
            name="BeanManager"
            auth="Container"
            type="javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager"
            factory="org.jboss.weld.resources.ManagerObjectFactory"
    />
</Context>
```

it seems that OmniFaces is load correctly, because Tomcat trace this line:

```
07-Jun-2019 12:30:51.823 INFORMACIÃ“N [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.omnifaces.ApplicationInitializer.logOmniFacesVersion Using OmniFaces version 2.7.1
```

On the other hand Tomcat doesn't throw any Omnifaces related error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you show us your xhtml file where de socket is used and notificar is called?

Comment: Hi @Raphael_S, thanks for reply. I think that, at server side, isn't necessary define the <o:socket> on xhtml. In fact, Omnifaces documentation only specifies that PushContext must used from any CDI/container managed artifact:
_"In WAR side, you can inject PushContext via `@Push` annotation on the given channel name in any CDI/container managed artifact such as `@Named`,  `@WebServlet`, etc wherever you'd like to send a push message and then invoke `PushContext.send(Object)` with any Java object representing the push message."_